# Cat to /dev/audio not working

Tags: dev

I downloaded some files and am trying to cat them to `/dev/audio` (for fun of course, I'm sure I could just play them) and I guess this is *supposed* to work, but it doesn't?

I get permission denied and even if I `sudo` it just does nothing...

Comment: Exact commands you're using could be helpful.

Comment: "/dev/audio"? What kind of operating system are you running? Such a thing doesn't exist on modern GNU/Linux. Well, it's not a special character device pointing to a sound card, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command from an elevated shell. When you try something like this:

```
sudo cat coolAudio.wav > /dev/audio
```

only the `cat` command is running as root; the redirection to `/dev/audio` is still being executed by the shell, which is running as your current user.

Try something like this instead:

```
sudo su -c 'cat coolAutio.wav > /dev/audio'
```

Comment: Sudprisingly, it still did not work. Do I have to redirect to another device if I am using headphones?